# ¿Cómo mostrar cierta información de una columna cuando esta cumpla una condición?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

En este caso muestro solo el nombre de la película y funciona bien:

Index HTML:

```
<% @peliculas.each do |peli| %>
  <h3 class="titulo"><%= link_to peli.name, peli %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Me gustaría que solo mostrase los nombres de las películas cuyo `year` (en la tabla indica el año también) sea `2017`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @peliculas.each do |peli| %>
<% if peli.year == Time.now.year %>
<h3 class="titulo">
<%= link_to peli.name, peli %></h3>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Si lo que quieres es un año específico entonces sustituye Time.now.year por el año que quieras.

```
<% @peliculas.each do |peli| %>
<% if peli.year == 2017 %>
<h3 class="titulo">
<%= link_to peli.name, peli %></h3>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Aunque soy partidiario de hacer este tipo de consultas en el controlador y no en la vista.

Comment: También podrias hacer una consulta desde tu controlador donde ya filtraras las películas que cumplieran con tu condición. Saludos

Comment: Has supuesto que el año que necesita el usuario es el corriente, no obstante en su pregunta dice 2017. Por tanto el año que viene este post no será válido.

Comment: gracias por aclararme

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, para hacer una cosa rápida y salvarme del apuro me a ido perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo nunca utilizar *datos duros* en tu código (i.e. `2017`), por lo que te funcionaría bien la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74662/42433) de Vicente.

Dicho lo anterior, yo te recomendaría utilizar una solución más robusta y mover la lógica al modelo.

#### Modelo

El modelo es el mejor lugar para establecer consultas, de esta forma tu código será más limpio y más fácil de mantener; para estos casos puedes generar métodos adicionales o `scopes`, yo prefiero el último y lo harías de la siguiente manera:

```
class Pelicula < ApplicationRecord
  scope :anio_actual -> { where(year: Time.now.year) } 
end
```

#### Controlador

Debido a que ya existe `anio_actual` en tu modelo, únicamente necesitas llamarlo en tu controlador para obtener los registros de ese año:

```
class PeliculasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @peliculas = Pelicula.anio_actual
  end
end
```

#### Vista

Tu vista ya no cambia, simplemente, itera `@peliculas` tal como lo estás haciendo:

```
<% @peliculas.each do |peli| %>
  <h3 class="titulo"><%= link_to peli.name, peli %></h3>
<% end %>
```

---

De esta forma tu código es mucho más flexible (y reutilizable), ya que en cualquier momento puedes llamar `anio_actual` sin tener que filtrar cada vez.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que quieres guardar todas las películas en `@peliculas` para utilizarlas en tu vista, esto lo harías poniendo en tu controlador:

```
@peliculas = Pelicula.all
```

Pero aún así tienes una sección de "Películas de este año" que quieres mostrar; en es caso, en tu vista solo agregarías `anio_actual` a `@peliculas`, así:

```
<% @peliculas.anio_actual.each do |peli| %>
  <h3 class="titulo"><%= link_to peli.name, peli %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Además, un `scope` regresa un objeto `ActiveRecord::Relation` lo que significa que puedes encadenarlo a otros métodos de `ActiveRecord`, por ejemplo:

```
Pelicula.where(... alguna condicion).anio_actual
```

En un principio pareciera más trabajo, pero los beneficios lo valen, y lo agradecerás más adelante cuando necesites ampliar tu aplicación o realizar cambios.

---

Por último, si forzosamente debes utilizar datos duros (e.g. `2017`), te recomiendo hacerlo utilizando **constantes**, por ejemplo (en tu modelo):

```
class Pelicula < ApplicationRecord
  YEAR = 2017

  scope :anio -> { where(year: YEAR) } 
end
```

O, si lo prefieres, en tu controlador:

```
class PeliculasController < ApplicationController
  YEAR = 2017

  def index
    @peliculas = Pelicula.where(year: YEAR)
  end
end
```

De esta forma será evidente que tienes un *dato duro* en tu código y podrá ser identificado (y modificado) de manera sencilla.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me lo leeré con atención y lo modificaré cuando ya esté todo un poco estabilizado. Genial!

Comment: @Gerry otra gran respuesta!

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Gracias! Espero sirva al OP!